# How to remove ripple effect from mat-stepper

Tags: css, angular, onfocus, mat-stepper, ripple-effect

tihs is the effect  when you hover you mose over matstepper
not able to figure how to disable this effect
[image]
want to remove ripple effect or focus effect or scrollable affect from mat-stepper
please help me out here
i have tried all the methods
not able to figure it out like ripple effect transparent and on-focus indicator

```
.stepper-qre {
        background: #F5F6F7;
        height: 88%;
    }
    
    .mat-horizontal-stepper-header-container {
        width: 65% !important;
        margin-left: 16.5%;
        /* display: -webkit-box !important; */
    }
    
    .mat-stepper-label-position-bottom .mat-horizontal-stepper-header {
        padding: 24px 0px !important;
    }
    
    ::ng-deep.mat-stepper-label-position-bottom.mat-stepper-horizontal-line {
        top: 34px !important;
    }
    
    .mat-stepper-label-position-bottom .mat-horizontal-stepper-header .mat-step-label {
        position: fixed;
        margin-top: 1%;
    }
    
    .stepper-qre.mat-step-icon-selected {
        background-color: #2699FB !important;
        color: white !important;
    }
    
    .stepper-qre.mat-step-icon-state-done {
        background-color: #2699FB !important;
        color: #fff !important;
    }
    
    .stepper-qre.mat-step-header .mat-step-icon {
        background-color: #C4C6CC !important;
        color: #fff;
    }
    
    ::ng-deep.mat-step-icon {
        height: 20px !important;
        width: 20px !important;
    }
    
    .mat-step-icon.mat-step-icon-state-notcompleted {
        background-color: #C4C6CC !important;
    }
    
    #activebutton:focus {
        border: none !important;
        outline: none !important;
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
    
    ::ng-deep.mat-step-header.mat-step-header-ripple {
        background-color: transparent !important;
    }
    
    .mat-ripple-element {
        transition-duration: 0ms !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a `disableRipple` property available for the stepper component, as per [the API](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/api).

Modified the [official stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fm2x9n?file=src/app/stepper-editable-example.html) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 1):

```
.mat-step-header:hover{
    background-color: white !important;
}
.mat-step-header.cdk-program-focused {
      background-color: white;
  }
.mat-step-header.cdk-mouse-focused{
    background-color: white;
}
.mat-step-header.cdk-focused{
    background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: this will help in changing background colour when hover or focused

Comment: This answer wold be much more helpful if you edited it to explain why it is correct and why it is the best answer for the question, so that others can learn from your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `disableRipple` to true:

```
<mat-stepper [disableRipple]="true" #stepper></mat-stepper>
```